# How can i make Magento ajax call to blocks, from controllers action

Tags: php, ajax, magento

How can I get output of :

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks"/>
```

inside a controller action?

In fact, I have to show links by AJAX.

Comment: This controller is requested by ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml()
```

please try this one, i have it checked and its working.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you can do this in your action function:

```
$linksBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/template_links');
echo $linksBlock->toHtml();
```

To get the content by ajax call, add this js script:

```
new Ajax.Updater('your_container', '/your_controller/your_action');
```

Comment: Well i get error with this : i did this with, but it show a blank page , no out put .$this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/template_links')->toHtml();

Comment: Yes i did echo but found a blank page: echo $linksBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/template_links')->toHtml();

Comment: when i call to header : echo $linksBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_header')->toHtml();       this results fine.

Comment: createBlock() is returning null for me. I'm wondering if the block you are trying to create has to be in the loaded layout or something? I'm not sure how to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

While the upvoted answers provided do answer the question, they both ignore the common situation where some specific action taken by your block loaded in with AJAX will prevent Magento redirects from working as expected.

Take the following situation:

- Block loaded through AJAX
- Block has 'Add to Cart' button (likely generated with the `getAddUrl($product)` helper)
- System Configuration >> Checkout >> Shopping Cart >> 'After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart' == NO

In this situation, after clicking 'Add to Cart', Magento will attempt to redirect the user using the CartController.php's `_goBack()` method. This causes the block you previously loaded through AJAX to be rendered on the page instead of the user actually being redirected to the page they were on.

---

To prevent this situation from happening, add an additional parameter `'your_param'` to the AJAX request that loads your block and give it a value of `Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()` (or whatever else you may want). Such as:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $yourUrl ?>',
    page: '<?php echo Mage::helper("core/url")->getCurrentUrl()?>'
})
```

Then, in your controller's relevant action method, add a quick condition to the beginning of the method, such as:

```
if (!this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->getRequest()->getParam('your_param'));
}
// ... existing controller code ...
// ... ie: $block->toHtml() ...
```

This will allow the user to return to their previous page after adding to cart. This also will provide a way for the user to return to the site if they happen to end up at your controller's URL.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/18152/s/ajax-blocks-6911/
This module allow you to load blocks using ajax, simply via your layout files